# How to use a loop to give `Future.wait()` a list o Futures

Tags: flutter, loops, asynchronous, future, wait

I'm using `Future.wait()` to get some data like in the code below:
I call the function `Future.delayed()` to wait 1 second between every call because I have a limit set to 1 request per second

```
    await Future.wait([

        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000))
            .then((value) => getPartNumber(1)
            .then((value) => addPartToList((value.data)))),

        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000))
            .then((value) => getPartNumber(2)
            .then((value) => addPartToList((value.data)))),

        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000))
            .then((value) => getPartNumber(3)
            .then((value) => addPartToList((value.data)))),

        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 4000))
            .then((value) => getPartNumber(4)
            .then((value) => addPartToList((value.data)))),

    ]);
```

So what I wanna do is to use a loop  instead of repeating the call manually 4 times

Comment: `await Future.wait([for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: i)).then(...).then(...)]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just use a for loop and wait 1 second in between to not exceed the rate limit.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  await getPartNumber(i).then((value) => addPartToList(value.data));
}
```

This also ensures that no more than one request per second comes in, as the time in between is waited.
Or if you want the waiting time to be handled the same way as in your code, the following also works:

```
await for(var i in Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (i)=>i).take(5)){
  if(i == 0) continue;
  await getPartNumber(i).then((value) => addPartToList(value.data));
}
```

Or if you really want to do it with Future.wait(), which I personally don't like, here's how to do it:

```
await Future.wait(
  Iterable.generate(4, (i)=>Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: i + 1))
    .then((value) => getPartNumber(i + 1))
    .then((value) => addPartToList(value.data))
);
```

or

```
await Future.wait([
  for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: i))
      .then((value) => getPartNumber(i)
      .then((value) => addPartToList(value.data))
]);
```

Comment: Oh thank you, i solved it by removing the brackets from the `for` loop

Comment: Yes, the brackets create a set or map in Dart. Depending on the content. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: just a little hint, remove the `await` keyword before `getPartNumber`, cuz I'm sending 4 requests to get 4 parts, so I don't have to wait to receive each part individually, I wrapped the 4 calls with `Future.wait()` to call them asynchronously and the wait for them to be finished

Comment: I figured that was the reason. But you can also handle this with a `Stream` (or with a `Timer`) without having to use `Future.wait`.

Comment: And if you don't wait for the requests, you may exceed the request per second. But of course I don't know how this rate limit is regulated with you.